# Trying to delete vowels from a string fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's wrong with this code? The aim is to check wether the entered string contains vowels and delete them

Here is the code:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    text = str(text)
    vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"
    for i in text:
        for i in vowel.lower():
            text = text.replace('i',' ')
        for i in vowel.upper():
            text = text.replace('i',' ')
    return text
```

It's a lesson on Codecademy

Comment: You tagged this with Python 3, but the original link to Code Academy uses their Python 2 online code session. My `str.translate()` answer would have to be adjusted for Python 2, so make sure you have the right tag there. For future reference: always include your code *here*, not with a link, and include the input you used, the output you got and what you expected to get instead.

Comment: `''.join([e for e in tgt if e.lower() not in 'aeiou'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to replace the *string with the value* `'i'`, not the contents of the variable `i`.

Your code is also very inefficient; you don't need to loop over every character in `text`; a loop over `vowel` is enough. Because you already include both upper and lowercase versions, the two loops over the lowercased and uppercased versions are in essence checking for each vowel *4 times*.

The following would be enough:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    text = str(text)
    vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"
    for i in vowel:
        text = text.replace(i,' ')
    return text
```

You are also replacing vowels with spaces, not just deleting them.

The fastest way to *delete* (rather than replace) all vowels would be to use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    return text.translate(text.maketrans('', '', 'aeiouAEIOU'))
```

The [`str.maketrans()` static method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) produces a mapping that'll delete all characters named in the 3rd argument.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see the toss-up between the `maketrans` and `text.translate(dict.fromkeys(map(ord, 'AEIOUaeiou')))`

Comment: @JonClements: it really should be made a function argument default instead but I didn't want to push the envelope too far here. `def anti_vowel(text, _mapping=str.maketrans('', '', 'aeiouAEIOU')): return text.translate(_mapping)`.

Comment: Indeed... all we're missing now is `re.sub('[aeiou]', '', text, flags=RE.I)` or something - then we can have a canonical answer to the question that gets asked several times each week...

Comment: @JonClements: hrm, in that case I also need to add in a Python 2 version; not sure I can squeeze that in right now. Perhaps tonight.